# JPA: Modeling one child table with multiple masters

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb

Need help to figure out how to model these entity beans. The requirement is: associate tags to both master1 and master2 tables (similar to tags that we assign to questions in SO).

Since I will have many master tables in the future, I created a single table for tags with a `master_type` column, where I'll store 1 if the tag is related to a row in master1, 2 if the tag is associated to a row in master2, and so on.

My issue is that I don't know how to declare this association in the Tag entity (code below). I have many `@JoinColumn`s, one for each master, but this doesn't seem right. Any thoughts?

```
@Entity
@Table (name="tags")
public class TagEntity {


    /*
     * Assign an id to the entry
     */ 
    @Id 
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;


    /*
     * This id identifies the tag that is associated to the master table
     */ 
    @Column(name="tag_id")
    private Intger tagId;


    /*
     * This id identifies the master table
     */ 
    @Column(name="master_id")
    private Integer master_Id;


    /*
     * This id identifies the type of master table
     */ 
    @Column(name="master_type")
    private Integer master_type;


    @JoinColumn(name = "master1_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Master1Entity master1;


    @JoinColumn(name = "master2_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Master2Entity master2;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, why you used @ManyToOne? As I understood one tag can be related to many tables. 
So what you need is to have a foreign key in each master entity. To achieve that in a nice way you can use a @MappedSuperclass like that:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Master{

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="tag")
  protected TagEntity tag;


  ...  // other shared fileds
}
```

and then declaring each Master class like that:

```
@Entity
public Master1 extends Master{
  ... //fields reserved only for entity master1
}
```

You can store a list of masters to which particular tag belongs to by putting in TagEntity @OneToMany (referencing Master class) but it's not obligatory and depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks iku. One entry in one of the master tables can have many entries in the tags table. Therefore, if I'm correct in the master table I should have something like  `protected Set<TagEntity> tags;`  instead of `protected TagEntity tag;`. In the tags table I will have a master_type and a master_id columns, master_type will identify the master table itself ('1' for master1, '2' for master2 and so on) and master_id will contain the id of the row in the respective master table. I'm struggling on modeling this with JPA.

Comment: In this scenario you will need @ManyToMany relation from master to tag (the owner of the relation would be master entity). I don't think you need any information about master in your tag table.

Comment: I reworded the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28030916/jpa-modeling-single-child-multiple-parent-tables), can you take a look? thanks