# Modeling single child/multiple parent tables

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I'm struggling to model the relationship between multiple tables (parents) that share a single table (child).

Given the following parent 1 table (the other parent tables 2,3 and so on are similar):

```
@Entity
@Table (name="parent1")
public class ParentEntity1 {

    @Id 
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    // relationship with child table

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ChildEntity> children;


    // other columns of parent 1


}
```

and the following child table:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="children")
public class ChildEntity {

    @Id 
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    // points to the parent type; 1, 2, and so on
    @Column(name="parent_type")
    private Integer parentType;

    @Column(name="parent_id")
    private Integer parentId;

    // some other data that belongs to ChildEntity

}
```

How do I persist one parent object and multiple children while creating the relationship? Note that the parent type is a column in the child table, and that both parent and child ids are auto-generated.

Comment: The `parentType` and `parentId` in `ChildEntity` is a bad idea. JPA can't support this.

Comment: To get rid of parentType my only option is to have one child table for each parent, what I tried to avoid but I don't see an alternative.

Comment: Do you have a database model for it?

Comment: A row in `ParentEntity1` can have N related rows in `Children`,  a row in `ParentEntity2` can have N related rows in `Children`, and so on. I want to keep a single table `Children` (instead of one for each `ParentEntityX`) because I have lots of `ParentEntityX` tables.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to actually attach the ParentEntity to the ChildEntity. In JPA this relation from m:1 is realized by @JoinColumn. You don't need to store parent type in a child entity - it would be a sign of a bad design. Type of a parent should be as close to its entity as possible. So simply put it in that entity:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="children")
public class ChildEntity {

    @Id Integer parentId;
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent")
    private ParentEntity parent;

    // some other data that belongs to ChildEntity
    //all setters and getters / lombok

}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class ParentEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ChildEntity> children;    


    @Column(name="parent_type")
    private Integer parentType;

    //all setters and getters / lombok
}


@Entity
@Table (name="parent1")
public class ParentEntity1 extends ParentEntity {

    @Id 
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;    

    // other columns specific to parent 1

    //all setters and getters / lombok
}


@Entity
@Table (name="parent2")
public class ParentEntity2 extends ParentEntity {

    @Id 
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;    

    // other columns specific to parent 2

    //all setters and getters / lombok
}
```

and to persist a parent with several children you do something like that:

```
ParentEntity pOne = new ParentEntity1();
ParentEntity pTwo = new ParentEntity2();

ChildEntity c1 = new ChildEntity();
ChildEntity c2 = new ChildEntity();
ChildEntity c3 = new ChildEntity();

Set<ChildEntity> childrenOne = new HashSet<>();
childrenOne.add(c1);
childrenOne.add(c2);

Set<ChildEntity> childrenTwo = new HashSet<>();
childrenTwo.add(c3);

pOne.setChildren(childrenOne);
pOne.setType(1);

// ... 
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(pOne);
em.getTransaction().commit();
// ...

pTwo.setChildren(childrenTwo);
pTwo.setType(2);


// ... 
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(pTwo);
em.getTransaction().commit();
// ...
```

and that's all. Note that you never instantiate ParentEntity class (as it's abstract). You can have multiple parent tables where each of them refers to single child table by the id. Moreover, you store information about the type of each subsequent parent entity in its class by inheritance from ParentEntity. I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: In the `Children` class you refer to the `ParentEntity`, is that a generic class or you meant `ParentEntity1` ? If the latter, what about `ParentEntity2`, `ParentEntity3` and so on?

Comment: What if the parent column in the Child entity is repeated for parent 1 and parent 2? How will the system know to which parent the row in Children is related to?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve. Do you mean a situation in which one child has to parents? Please provide illustrative example, otherwise I wont be able to help.

Comment: Assume you have a row in `ParentEntity1` with id=1 and a row in `ParentEntity2` also with id=1. Now I want to add children to each row. In your model, the `parent` column in `ChildEntity` will have a value of 1 in both cases. Now assume I query `ParentEntity1` with id=1 and retrieve its children, how will the system differentiate the children of `ParentEntity1` from the children of `ParentEntity2` if all the children have `parent` = 1?

Comment: It's magic ;) The differentiation is realized by the means of inheritance no by the integer number. Following your example - in each of children of those two parents, there will be an attribute (column) with reference to ParentEntity. And ORM will for sure know of what type it is. I don't know how you'd like to query (via jpql or cirteria query) but you can use explicit names of those entities. When you will be retrieving any child and you would like to determine the parent type you can always use instanceof operator.

Comment: And one more thing ids in well designed JPA model should be completely hidden from what's going on in code or queries. You don't need them (except rare cases when someone decides to use business keys as physical ids).

Comment: thanks. you say `in each of children of those two parents, there will be an attribute (column) with reference to ParentEntity` where is that column declared?

Comment: private ParentEntity parent; in ChildEntity

Comment: but isn't `ParentEntity parent` the id of the parent instead of the parent type? what would be the value of `parent` in the children of my previous example where both `ParentEntity1` and `ParentEntity2` have id = 1?

Comment: Yes but as I showed in the example above - it can be instantiated with ParentEntity1, ParentEntity2 or whatever subclass of ParentEntity and you dont need anything else. You will always be able to determine the exact type by the means of language/ORM mechanisms. I think you have quite good understanding of db modeling you lack some basic concepts from Java like i.e. inheritance.

Comment: thanks, but `in the database` what would be the value of parent in the children of my previous example where both ParentEntity1 and ParentEntity2 have id = 1? both parents have children and parent1/parent2 are different tables

Comment: Good question. I don't think it would be possible for the ORM to create and persist Parent1 and Parent2 with the same id in such a case. Also I'm not sure how above schema will be parsed to database level.